# Base64 encoded MX records in TXT records

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, encoding, txt-record

A lot of domains hosted by Namecheap contain strange DNS TXT records that appear to be base64 encoded, that when decoded look like a weird kind of MX record - having the structure of both a priority and then a domain. What are these for? There does not appear to be any documentation anywhere regarding these. There are tens of thousands of examples of these, yet there is no clear purpose or documentation. Does anyone know what these are used for?

Some examples:

- `everythingforsight.org.` has a TXT record of `MAltYWlsLmV2ZXJ5dGhpbmdmb3JzaWdodC5vcmcuCg==` which decodes to
  `0 mail.everythingforsight.org.`
- `1eyeworks.com.` has a TXT record of `MAltYWlsLjFleWV3b3Jrcy5jb20uCg==` which decodes to `0   mail.1eyeworks.com.`

Comment: What did Namecheap say about it?

Comment: They said it wasn't anything to do with them and that they had no idea what they were for.

Comment: How did you retrieve these records? By looking at Namecheap's DNS management panel, or externally?

Comment: Externally, just by doing DNS lookups.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is this:

[NOTE 1:In case you do not want to interrupt the functionality of current email services before the creation of mailboxes with us we have an alternative verification method that implies a TXT record adding on the side of the DNS provider. To get a value of a TXT record that needs to be added, please contact our Support Team.](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1340/2176/namecheap-private-email-records-for-domains-with-thirdparty-dns/)

Comment: Yes, "authentication" is what makes more sense. However the content of the page linked too (regarding the `MX` records) do not match at all the 2 domains in question, but maybe they have changed their configuration and `TXT` records are often not cleaned up after the fact.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing they did some migration with little/no cleanup after.

Comment: This could be it, however the 'alternate TXT record' format isn't specified so we can't be sure it is this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ask the owner of those zones as they are theoretically responsible for the content, not the DNS provider.

It may be for some sort of "authentication" as `TXT` records are often (ab)used for that, or just some bad tool. Or loose attempts at some sort of zone integrity checks.

Anyway, they don't "match". `everythingforsight.org.` has currently 3 MX records, none of them using `mail.everythingforsight.org.` as mail exchanger.

In fact, instead of asking Namecheap you should ask the company behind `web-hosting.com` as this is the base of the email exchangers used in the 2 domains you gave as example. Hum.... `web-hosting.com` seems to be Namecheap anyway too :-)

Comment: That was an observation I had made too, most of these domains with these records the domain in the encoded record is `mail.<domain>` and they do not match the actual MX records of the domain.